# how to set prohibited area for global path plan

Tags: ros, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, All,

on my map, there are crowed places.

how can I set prohibit area so that global path planner would never attempt to route through these areas?

regards

Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187015/how-to-set-prohibited-area-for-global-path-plan/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-18**:
Are you using Hydro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can, for example, modify the map manually using your favourite image editing software to englobe with a black polygon the areas that you want the planner to avoid.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-18**:
I agree on @Martin Peris. I also think that it is the easiest in methods we choose.

**Comment by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on 2014-07-19**:
hi, Martin,

thanks for the advice.
I have a concern on this.
will the additional lines affect the localization performance when the robot comes to that corner? I am using AMCL for localization.

regards
Ray.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-19**:
Hi @dreamcase, yes modifying the map in such way might have an impact on the accuracy of localisation depending on what kind of sensor you are using, how big the "exclusion zone" is, the speed of the robot etc... But it might be worth to give it a try